# National water territories and exclusive economic zones around artificial structures

Tags: international-law, international, united-nations

Obviously I am asking inspired by the China's actions but I am more interested  in the international law and treaties on such cases on on general level.

What do international treaties say about claiming artificial island to claim territorial waters and exclusive economic zone around on it?

Some more specific questions:

1. Is is even possible to claim an artificial island?
2. Does it have to have some kind of "natural basis"?
3. Could you build an artificial peninsula and claim waters around it? E.g. would an airport on an artificial island change the status of neighbouring waters?

(*I hope this is right SE, and I hope this is not too broad.*)

Comment: I believe (but have no source to prove) that this is a legal grey area, because the international treaties regarding territorial waters predate the times when building artificial islands to extend a sea-borders was technically possible.

Comment: It might also be useful to look at legal precedent regarding the effect of [land reclamation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_reclamation) on sea borders. This is also an artificial method to extend a coast line and is practiced for centuries. Sure, we are just talking about a few hundred meters here, but there were border disuputes about less area.

Answer (score 8):

### 1. Is is even possible to claim an artificial island?

No, it is not possible to use an artificial island to establish an exclusive economic zone.

The 'UNITED NATIONS CONVENTION ON THE LAW OF THE SEA' Part V Article 60 Item 7 states:

> Artificial islands, installations and structures and the safety zones
>   around them may not be established where interference may be caused to
>   the use of recognized sea lanes essential to international navigation.

The 'UNITED NATIONS CONVENTION ON THE LAW OF THE SEA' Part V Article 60 Item 8 states:

> Artificial islands, installations and structures do not possess the
>   status of islands. They have no territorial sea of their own, and
>   their presence does not affect the delimitation of the territorial
>   sea, the exclusive economic zone or the continental shelf.

### 2. Does it have to have some kind of "natural basis"?

The island can only have a "natural basis" if it stands above water at high tide.

The 'UNITED NATIONS CONVENTION ON THE LAW OF THE SEA' Part II Article 13 Item 2 describes an island of "low-tide elevation":

> A low-tide elevation is a naturally formed area of land which is
>   surrounded by and above water at low tide but submerged at high tide.
>   Where a low-tide elevation is situated wholly or partly at a distance
>   not exceeding the breadth of the territorial sea from the mainland or
>   an island, the low-water line on that elevation may be used as the
>   baseline for measuring the breadth of the territorial sea.

Because the natural islands in dispute were completely submerged at high tide before artificial alterations, the following law applies:

The 'UNITED NATIONS CONVENTION ON THE LAW OF THE SEA' Part II Article 13 Item 2:

> Where a low-tide elevation is wholly situated at a distance exceeding the breadth of the territorial sea from the mainland or an
>   island, it has no territorial sea of its own.

Where "Breadth of the territorial sea" is described in Part II Article 3 as:

> Every State has the right to establish the breadth of its territorial sea up to a limit not exceeding 12 nautical miles, measured from baselines determined in accordance with this Convention.

China's nearest shoreline is more than 400 miles away from the Spratly islands.

### 3. Could you build an artificial peninsula and claim waters around it? E.g. would an airport on an artificial island change the status of neighbouring waters?

No. The items quoted above from 'UNITED NATIONS CONVENTION ON THE LAW OF THE SEA' prevent this.

Comment: Nice answer, but I'm not sure the third answer follows from the other quotes.  They all address *islands*, but if it's connected to your mainland (i.e. a peninsula) that wouldn't necessarily apply.

Comment: Thanks for great answer/research. A nitpick though: so does the transported sand counts as an artificial island/installation? I would suspect that an oil platform or other construction does. But sand look a little bit grey area, because how would one differentiate between naturally aggregated and human-transported. I assume it could a matter of interpretation/debate if it's not defined well. I guess to pull something like that one would have to exclude "the POI" from V.60.8. The definition of "artificial island" would complement this nicely.